# Unable to open Dockerfile.dev in intellij editor

Tags: intellij-idea

I am facing a strange problem with my `Dockerfile.dev` in my `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)` It's not getting associated with any file type and on double-clicking it, it doesn't open. Anyone else faced any similar issue?

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you [map it here](https://i.imgur.com/hkwVQrA.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types, add a new mapping for this extension/name:

[image: mapping]